# Spring(-Boot) autowiring is always null with naked initializr project

Tags: java, spring, service, autowired

I'm a Spring and Spring-Boot starter and I just created my first Spring-Vaadin Application. Real nice how basic save and load of objects work over the CRUD-Interface.

So my problem is, that the autowired mapping wont work with a service I created.

My main-program (MainProgramApplication.java) looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainProgramApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainProgramApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The problematic class is the MainProgramUI.java:

```
@Widgetset("AppWidgetset")
@SpringUI
public class Imdb2BoerseUI extends UI {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6573726003150257919L;

    private final VerticalLayout masterLayout;
    private VerticalLayout resultLayout;

    .......

    @Autowired
    private MediaService mediaService;

    public Imdb2BoerseUI() {
           mediaService.doSomethring(); //mediaService is null
    }
}
```

So i don't really know why this serivce is always empty :(
I found many examples with spring and the autowired annotation... I tried most versions :D

So my last try was this (of the MediaService.java -> MediaServiceImpl.java )

MediaService.java:

```
@Service
@Configurable
public interface MediaService extends GenericAccessService<MediaObject>{
    public List<MediaObject> getItemsBySearchString(String filterString);
}
```

MediaServiceImpl.java:

```
public class MediaServiceImpl implements MediaService{

    @Autowired
    private SearchQueryRepository searchQueryRepository; //works

    @Autowired
    private MediaObjectRepository MediaObjectRepository;


    public MediaServiceImpl() {
        doAnything();
    }
............
}
```

And to be complete the master GenericAccessService-Interface:

```
public interface GenericAccessService<T> {
    List<T> searchInDataBase(String filterPrefix, long firstResult);
    long countInDataBase(String filterPrefix);
}
```

So my short beginner question is: why the mediaService is always null? Where are the differences between the usage of general Spring tutorials and the usage of spring-boot? Are there things to avoid when using spring-boot in difference to spring in general?

Thanks in advance.
Ben

---

Here my folder structure so far:

```
mainProgram
│   MainProgramUI.java
│   MainProgramApplication.java
├───entities
│       MediaObject.java
│       MediaObjectRepository.java
│       SearchQuery.java
│       SearchQueryRepository.java
├───services
│       MediaService.java
│       MediaServiceImpl.java
│       .....
└───suggestion
        GenericAccessService.java       
        .....
```

---

### EDIT

Okay the answer of zapl worked in that case. Nut now:

I have some classes and some CustomComponents which I added to my MainUI. One of this components have a normal Constructor like:

```
MyCustomUiComponent(MyCustomVlauesObject a);
```

But I don't want to pass the my singleton class thru ALL ComponentClasses down to the class I need it.

In TopUiComponent.java I create instances of MiddleUiComponent.java and in this class I create many objects of BottomUiComponent.java.

So if I want to have a Service, or regular Object managed by Spring in BottomUiComponent.java, I have to pass it thru all constructors of the UI -elements?

So I attached my current state of a project. And in class MovieComponent.java I want to autowire a singleton class 'ImageCache'.

But I really didn't get it to work. Maybe someone could just take a short look and hit me with the solution T_T

thanks

http://tinyurl.com/nunnyfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `null` at that point. Spring isn't as magical as it seems.

```
public Imdb2BoerseUI() {
       mediaService.doSomethring(); //mediaService is null
}
```

That's the constructor and even with Spring's injection, it's the first place in the lifecycle of your class. When Spring injects fields, it can only do so after calling that constructor. There is otherwise no entity on which it could set fields.

You have 2 choices: Let spring inject directly in the constructor:

```
@Autowired
public Imdb2BoerseUI(MediaService mediaService) {
       this.mediaService = mediaService;
       mediaService.doSomethring(); //mediaService is no longer null
}
```

Or do all the initialization after spring has injected the fields by giving spring a method to call once it's ready:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    mediaService.doSomethring();  
}
```

Constructor injection is the cleanest way ( http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/ ), post init methods are more convenient though.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i edited my question, because - I have to be honest - I didn't really get the point....

Comment: @Smoki when you use dependency injection you basically get rid of all `new` in your code and instead let spring figure out which things to pass through where. Every class just needs to declare what it needs wired. And then you also need to provide the things to wire at some place. via `@Component` for example. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html if you like the complicated doc